# Accessing Home directory of ArcMap using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, workspace

I want to access to a directory and set that as a arcpy.env.workspace in my Python Script Tool. However, this workspace depends on users so I cannot just use my own folders.

Is there a way to access Home directory (where .mxd file is saved) in arcpy?

I tried retrieving the directory from os.getcwd but that refers to "c:\windows\system32" where ArcMap is accessing.

Comment: Try os.environ.get('USERPROFILE') to get to C:\Users\<username> folder then append 'my documents' to get to the users' documents folder. Caveat: this only works on Microsoft Windows OS.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this won't work if the project file is saved on other disk drive. Or perhaps I can force the user to use it on C drive. I will also check what os module can do. I am thinking that if ArcMap can make that access there would be a way to do so in arcpy as well.

Comment: Are you trying to get to the path that the *open MXD* is saved in? That is arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT').filePath
for the MXD file and os.path.dirname(arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT').filePath)
for the folder the MXD is in (returns '' if the MXD isn't saved).There is only one *home* which should be in the path os.path.join(os.environ.get('USERPROFILE'),r'Documents\ArcGIS')

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I am expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the folder that the currently open MXD is in you can use `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT').filePath`, this returns '' (an empty string) if the MXD isn't saved and the full path to the current MXD if it is saved.

Using the [os.path module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) you can find the folder the document is in with `os.path.dirname`, thus `os.path.dirname( arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT').filePath )` is the folder that the current MXD is saved in. Be sure to `import os` before attempting to use it.

In ArcGIS Pro the object for the current document is [arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/alphabeticallistofclasses.htm), from [the examples](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/tutorial-getting-started-with-arcpy-mp.htm), the syntax would be `os.path.dirname( arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT").filePath )`.